# Did Soviets/Russians perform any crewed (intentionally) suborbital flights?

Tags: crewed-spaceflight, russia, sub-orbital, soviet-union

Gagarin went directly to the orbit - the first manned flight was orbital. I don't know about any other Soviet or Russian spaceflights that wouldn't be orbital - except for some odd aborted launch or other unforeseen difficulties.

I wonder though, if they performed any manned suborbital launches at a later date - something like what Blue Origin plans to do commercially. Or maybe do they plan something like this? Or is Russia "Orbital only"?

Comment: A cite from wikipedia about [Vostok](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vostok_programme)
"The first manned spaceflight, Vostok 1 in April 1961, was preceded by several preparatory flights. In mid-1960, the Soviets learned that the Americans could launch a sub-orbital manned spaceflight as early as January 1961. Korolev saw this as an important deadline, and was determined to launch a manned orbital mission before the Americans launched their manned suborbital mission."  
Sputnik, Laika, Gagarin were all orbital missions

Comment: Just for the sake of completeness. There was a wide program of suborbital launches involving dogs starting from the very first Korolev's R1 rocket. See this table (in Russian) for details https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Собаки_в_космосе

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There were only four manned Russian programs:

## Vostok

No suborbital flights were made. [See](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vostok_programme#Manned_flights)

## Voskhod

No suborbital flights were made. [See](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voskhod_programme)

## Soyuz

There was a two suborbital mission: a failed Soyuz launch in 1975, [Soyuz 7K-T No.39](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soyuz_7K-T_No.39)

- Its apogee was 192km high, for a flight time of 21min.
- Made it to space but clearly short of orbit.

The failure was due to an improper separation from stage 2 and 3.

And [MS-10](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soyuz_MS-10), a failure in 2018, not quite reaching space (93km).

Another one comes to mind: the failed launch of Soyouz T-10-1

In this case, the rocket caught fire on the launchpad and the escape tower saved the cosmonaut by making a short hop (but not reaching space).

## Buran

- A few manned [atmospheric flight](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buran_programme#Atmospheric_test_flights)s were made.
- The longest one lasted 36min.
- One orbital robotic flight was made.

So we have one accidental sub-orbital flight, and few atmospheric flights.

The answer is **no** for intentional sub-orbital flights.

Comment: The question is about intentional suborbital flights, not launch failures

Comment: COnveresly, this is evidence that the answer is actually No.  There were only launch failures.

Comment: The [Voskhod program](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voskhod_programme) followed Vostok and preceded Soyuz. It included two crewed flights.